# How to add a Fragment to a tab in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is my MapFragment:

```
public class MapFragment extends SherlockFragment {

    public static final String TAG = "mapFragment";

    public MapFragment() {}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup vg, Bundle data) {
        // The Activity created the MapView for us, so we can do some init stuff.
        Exchanger.mMapView.setClickable(true);
        Exchanger.mMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); // If you want.

        /*
         * If you're getting Exceptions saying that the MapView already has
         * a parent, uncomment the next lines of code, but I think that it
         * won't be necessary. In other cases it was, but in this case I
         * don't this should happen.
         */
        /*
         * final ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) Exchanger.mMapView.getParent();
         * if (parent != null) parent.removeView(Exchanger.mMapView);
         */

        return Exchanger.mMapView;
    }
}






This is my LocationTabActivity: 




public class LocationTabActivity extends RoboSherlockMapActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener{



    private MapFragment mMapFragment;
    private MyListFragment mMyListFragment;

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Exchanger.mMapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapView1);


        getSupportActionBar()

          .setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);



    ActionBar.Tab newTab0 = getSupportActionBar().newTab();

    newTab0.setText("Location");

    ActionBar.Tab newTab1 = getSupportActionBar().newTab();

    newTab1.setText("Map");

    newTab0.setTabListener(this);

    newTab1.setTabListener( this);

    getSupportActionBar().addTab(newTab0);

    getSupportActionBar().addTab(newTab1);




    }
```

I'm finding it quite difficult to add the fragment to the Android tab. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://marakana.com/s/post/1250/android_fragments_tutorial) may help you.

You can also implement fragments in API levels lower than 11 as well. For this you need to do follow these steps:- Add android-support-v4.jar to you project. Find this jar at SDK-PATH/extras/android/compatibility/v4/. Copy this into your libs folder in the root of your project and add it to your project build path. Use FragmentActivity instead of Activity. To get FragmentManager use getSupportFragmentManager instead of getFragmentManager.